# Customize devise sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, registration, customization

I'm new to the rails world so this can be a stupid question, but I cannot find the answer...

when I access a link like that:

www.domain.com/users/sign_up?email=some@email.com

I would like to have my "e-mail" field filled in with this parameter(some@email.com, in this case)

Any ideas of how can I achieve this (using devise) ?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The answer:

```
<%= text_field :email, :value => params[:email] %>
```

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question, and then accept it!

Answer (score 1):

You must use the name of the email field which is user[email] so `www.domain.com/users/sign_up?user[email]=some@email.com` I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work, I did exactly what you said, my input has the right name, but it is not filled in. Any idea ?

Comment: It does work for me, Im using Devise 1.0.8 and Rails 2.3.8 for testing. Did you modify your routes or change params in your controller ?

Comment: Again, thanks for the answer, I find another way. just setting the value of my text_field as the param worked. An example: <%= text_field :email, :value => params[:email] %>